# How do I show an input field if a radio button is checked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a radio button called "other," and when checked, I want a input field called "other-text" to show up. It's fairly simple, but I've been failing all morning.

```
<input name="ocalls" type="radio" name="other" id="other-radio" value="Yes"><b>Other</b><br />
<input type="text" name="other-text" id="other-text" style="display:none" />
```

Here is my javascript:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("input[name=other]").change(function(){          


        if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
        jQuery("#other-text").show()
        }
        else {
        jQuery("#other-text").hide();
        }                                                            
   });
});
```

JSFiddle of the failure. http://jsfiddle.net/Wpt3Y/532/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wpt3Y/537/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
jQuery("#other-radio").change(function(){...
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go this way. Tried to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) but realised you use old version of `jquery`

```
jQuery("input:radio[name='ocalls']").change(function(){                                          
            if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
                jQuery("#other-text").show();
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#other-text").hide();
            }                                                            
       });
```

[example with radio](http://jsfiddle.net/Wpt3Y/541/)

Instead you can use checkbox:

**html**

```
<input name="ocalls" type="checkbox" name="other" id="other-radio" value="Yes"><b>Other</b><br />
<input type="text" name="other-text" id="other-text" style="display:none" />
```

**js**

```
jQuery("input:checkbox[name='ocalls']").change(function(){                              
            if ($(this).attr("checked") == true) {
                jQuery("#other-text").show();
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#other-text").hide();
            }                                                            
       });
```

[example with checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/Wpt3Y/545/)

Answer (score 0):

Just updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wpt3Y/539/

```
<pre><input type="radio" name="other" id="other-radio" value="Yes"><b>Other</b></pre>
```

Your code works, you simply mistyped your radio input, it had two name attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<input name="ocalls" type="radio" name="other" id="other-radio" value="Yes">
   <b>Other</b><br />
</input>

<input type="text" name="other-text" id="other-text" style="display: none;" />          
</form>

jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("#other-radio").change(function(){          

            if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
            jQuery("#other-text").show()
            }
            else {
            jQuery("#other-text").hide();
            }                                                            
       });
});
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that toggle effect you can use this code with the checkbox.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("input[name=ocalls]").change(function(){                      
        if($(this).attr("checked"))
        {
           $("#other-text").show(); 
        }
        else
        {
            $("#other-text").hide();
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not working because you have `name` attribute twice in `radio` button.

use this:

```
<input type="radio" name="other" id="other-radio" value="Yes">
```

remove `name="ocalls"` attribute.